# Where do I find successor packages and task-related package recommendations?

Tags: best-practices, obsolete

As [l2tabu](https://ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu?lang=de) already hasn't been updated in 6 years, is there any other place to get to know

1. which packages became obsolete / superseded by which ones / have been improved by which ones?
2. which packages are currently "recommended" for task / area X?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the problem about it not having been updated in 6 years? Does it need an update?

Comment: mathtools did not supersede amsmath. It extends it with very useful additions and corrections.

Comment: why do you think there should be such a list? latex has millions of users and thousands of them have produced publicly available packages. No one ranks these. If someone writes an improved or just different package, it does not mean that the maintainer of the original package stops maintaining that, or even knows about the new one, it just means a user has a choice of packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You basically answered your own question: It's the *complete* lack of oversight. If I maintain or just use a package and an improved one comes into light, I *would like* to know about it. E.g. (@TeXnician) if `mathtools` corrects `amsmath` there is zero reason for me to continue using `amsmath` (but to compile old documents I don't want to touch). @MaestroGlanz The key point here is: *I don't know!* Probably. That's what `l2tabu` is about. The package landscape develops.

Comment: @Suuuehgi would you ask that about perl or python or C programs? If you write a program in python and somewhere on the internet someone writes a program with overlapping functionality, would you expect some third party to assess the two programs and declare one superior and tell the mainainer of the inferior one that they should stop mainaining it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle **1** In my humble view, the e.g. Python landscape (1) is way more centralized (`numpy`, `scipy` and alike) and (2) there is no such thing as "I improve my package by creating a new one" / the backward-compatibility desire that's a big part of the mess. **2** (1) That's what happening and happening more visible since the user-bases are way larger. (2) That's his/her decision.

Comment: lots of packages have not been updated in 6 years so that is not surprising (I have packages that have not been updated in 25 years, but are maintained). There are newer array packages (`nicemarix` and `tabularray` for example) but their arrival is not the reason for deprecating `tabu`. `tabu` does not work with current latex and gives errors if used, so the issues with it are completly unrelated to successor packages, you need to stop using it even if no newer packages were available. But that is a specific issue about one broken package not a general feature of latex package distribution

Comment: @TeXnician I incorporated your hint into the question. :)
@DavidCarlisle Maybe I haven't been clear enough in my question but I generally don't have any issues with packages that are not updated for 25 years *and* are still up-to-date. Thank you for the pointer to `nicematrix`! ;)

Comment: I agree that I cringe a bit when I see some LaTeX tutorials giving advice that have been obsolete for 15 years, but as other pointed out there isn't any governing body deciding everything about packages.
However, personally, every 5 years or so, I look up every package I use on CTAN. If there is a mention that a package has been superceded, its replacement is usually indicated so I can update my class file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the nearest one gets to an official source is *The LaTeX Companion* (TLC), where Frank and others try to give a sense of the current landscape. That's a serious effort, and TLC2 is now quite long-in-the-tooth. Luckily, TLC3 is on the horizon and will I suspect give guidance on a lot of this.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! TLC3 is scheduled for 2023 -- maybe [slightly earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/612586/37806).